# spring 3 + jpa 2 - fully qualified class name in queries

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa-2.0

I've successfully configured spring 3 + jpa 2.0. When I do:

```
em.createQuery("from SystemUser",SystemUser.class).getResultList();
```

I receive following exception :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: SystemUser is not mapped [from SystemUser]
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1201)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1147)
```

But when i type fully qualified class name:

```
em.createQuery("from com.aims.domain.SystemUser",SystemUser.class).getResultList();
```

It works. Does anyone what configurations i missed out.

My persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence-unit name="aims" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
     <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect"/>
        <!-- value="create" to build a new database on each run; value="update" to modify an existing database; value="create-drop" means the same as "create" but also drops tables when Hibernate closes; value="validate" makes no changes to the database -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8"/>

    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

My appContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">


    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/*.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true" />


    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>

    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" >
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.aims.service" />
</beans>
```

For your information i'm running test case using junit with following annotation:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml" })
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = false)
@Transactional
```

Comment: could you please post your persistence xml

Comment: would it work if you add the class to your persistence-unit?

Comment: please post the relevant part of your spring configuration file

Comment: if i add class still it doesnt works. i posted spring conf file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you have compiled, as a resource, persistence.xml into the jar that contains your database entities and that the name of the persistence unit (persistenceUnitName property for Spring's LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean) is set properly?

Sample persistence.xml (under META-INF/ in the jar that contained your entities):

```
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation=" http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"/>
</persistence>
```

Sample Spring Config:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
      <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

---

**EDIT**: Also, you named your entity: AMTB_SYSTEM_USERS, so your query should be `from AMTB_SYSTEM_USERS` instead of `from SystemUsers`

```
2011-01-25 18:44:02,862 DEBUG [EntityBinder] - Import with entity name AMTB_SYSTEM_USERS
```

Comment: All configuration above i've done it. except packaging resources as jar. Since i making web application all classes and configurations will be in war file

Comment: Can you try separating out the database entities into its own jar (with the persistence.xml) and including that jar as a dependency in your war?

Comment: @Adelave I'd reconsider that. Putting everything in one War is bad design. I'd create one jar for the persistence layer, one for the service layer etc. and I'd put these in WEB-INF/lib

Comment: regardless bad design or not, is separating that into jar will solve the problem ? i've tried to separate persistence.xml and data access classes into separate jar, and included in my war files. Still got same problem.

Comment: @Adelave I have running an application where the war contains a jar which contains the persistence.xml and the entity classes, and it works without full qualified names - so I guess that this is NOT the cause.

Comment: @Adelave Just wondering, do you have the top-level <persistence> node in your persistence.xml?

Comment: yes i have, i cut it when i paste here it doesnt show properly :p

Comment: @Adelave did you try adding:

<property name="persistenceUnitName" value="aims"/>

to your spring config like the example above?

Comment: My bad, i've changed  @Entity(name="AMTB_SYSTEM_USERS")  to 
@Entity
@Table(name="AMTB_SYSTEM_USERS") , now it works. Thanks